# Redirecting specific requests from old domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I'm already redirecting an old domain via a 301 redirect but I've noticed that I'm getting lots of requests for certain files and pages from the old site. How can I redirect these requests so that it just loads the new site? I'd like to do this for specific files only.

Edit: The website is on shared hosting, but I can edit the web.config file of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create an entry in IIS for each file. Create the path structure on disk under the site's root and on that page in IIS create a redirect for the file in question. You can use notepad and explorer to make those files.

That's the fastest manual way I know of in IIS6. IIS7 should be easier tho. In IIS7 you could edit the application host file.

EDIT: see also ~ [Which redirection is better - web.config or global.asax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175443/which-redirection-is-better-web-config-or-global-asax)

EDIT: see also ~ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228302.aspx

Comment: How can I do this with web.config only? I don't have access to IIS as it's shared hosting.

Comment: I believe the version my host has is II7.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is running IIS version 7 or higher you can use URL Rewrite for that which does allow you to specify the mappings in web.config http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite
You can either create a generic rule that redirects all traffic based on regular expressions, or create a rewrite map to setup a table.
See the section "Moving Directories" at [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151203210004/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/carlosag/archive/2008/09/02/iis7urlrewriteseo.aspx)